# Least Common Subsequence with optimized space (two columns, since it's Markovian)

Tags: java, string, optimization, dynamic-programming, longest-substring

I'm trying to write LCS of two String objects using bottom-up dynamic programming. I'm able to get it to work properly with `O(mn)` space. However, as I could see, I don't need all the previous columns. So, I tried to modify it to get it fit in 2 columns so space become `O(m)`. However, it's not working for all inputs (for example, to this: `abcabc` and `abcbcca`). What am I missing here? NOT HW, NOT CONTEST nothing. Practicing DP.

```
public int longestCommonSubsequence(String input) {
    char[] firstStr = this.string.toCharArray();
    char[] secondStr = input.toCharArray();
    int[][] maxLength = new int[firstStr.length+1][2];

    for(int i=0; i <= firstStr.length; i++) {
      maxLength[i][0] = 0;
    }
    for(int j=0; j < 2; j++) {
      maxLength[0][j] = 0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < firstStr.length; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j < secondStr.length; j++) {
        if(firstStr[i] == secondStr[j]) {
          maxLength[i+1][1] = 1 + maxLength[i][0];
        }
        else {
          maxLength[i+1][1] = maxLength[i][1]>maxLength[i+1][0]?maxLength[i][1]:maxLength[i+1][0];
        }
      }
      //Copy second row to first row
      for(int l =0; l < firstStr.length; l++) {
        maxLength[l][0] = maxLength[l][1];
      }
    }

    return maxLength[firstStr.length -1][0];
  }
```

Comment: Are the first two for loops supposed to be embedded? (and maxLenght[i][j] = 0;)

Comment: No. That would mean that all the elements in the two column matrix will be zero. Not what I want. I want first column and first row of that two column matrix to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

This has two problems:

```
    if(firstStr[i] == secondStr[j]) {
        maxLength[i+1][1] = 1 + maxLength[i][0];
        // check here if maxLength[i+1][1] is greather than the last max length
    }
    else {
        maxLength[i+1][1] = maxLength[i][1]>maxLength[i+1][0]?maxLength[i][1]:maxLength[i+1][0];
         // absolutely wrong: maxLength[i+1][1] = 0;
    }
```

Here can see the algorithm with micro optimization.

```
public static int lcs(String s0, String s1) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    int [][]lengths = new int[2][s1.length()+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < s0.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
            if (s0.charAt(i) == s1.charAt(j)) {
                lengths[0][j+1] = lengths[1][j] + 1;
                if (lengths[0][j+1] > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = lengths[0][j+1];
                }
            } else {
                lengths[0][j+1] = 0;
            }
        }
        int []temp = lengths[0];
        lengths[0] = lengths[1];
        lengths[1] = temp;
    }
    return maxLength; 
}
```